# How does Toxic set work in Raid : Shadow Legend?

Tags: raid-shadow-legends

I started playing this game two days ago, so I'm pretty new to it.
I'm not that lost as I'm already playing Summoner wars for more than a year and a lots of mechanics are the same. 
I've found some artifacts that don't have equivalent effect in SW, like toxic set, freeze set, sleep set and others sets like this, applying debuf when attack enemy. 
I have a question about these sets :
**Does multi-hit attacks give multiple chances to apply the debuf?**
As an example, does a champion that attack twice with a toxic set has a chance to apply two DoT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to clarify there is a difference between multi-hit attack and an attack that hits multiple foes (AOE).

A multi hit attack (one that say hits a single opponent 3x) has a single chance to trigger an artifact set debuff.

In your example of Banshee, her attack that hits multiple foes one time (AOE) That means each foe has a chance to receive the debuff. 
a check is made on each opponent with % chance to occur, increased by your accuracy, decreased by your opponent's resistance.

Comment: Thank you for addressing both cases, it makes this answer very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Artifact Sets activate once per Skill use, so multi-hit attacks count as a single hit when applying Set debuffs

Comment: Does every target have same result ? Example : I got Banshee, which have two aoe, so only one hit but on every opponents. If one trigger the artifact effect, does all others also suffer the effect ?